# Struggling to get my promises to work in an array loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, loops, es6-promise

I have been struggling with this issue for a week and have researched myself close to death. I am a total newbie. I have managed to grasp the crux of promises, but I am failing to see how to include this in a loop.
I have an app that is looking through an array. There is some validation of the array against a mongoose database (which is taking time to run). I am trying to push items into a new array based on some of this validation. I know the validation is working because of the console log in the loop. However my final array is not waiting for the loop to finish. Which means I need to put the loop into a promise, or well I think, but the issue is that I don't know how to resolve it. Current output is a blank array instead of the validated array. Here is my code:

```
//dummy data of an array - this is originally extracted from a mongoose DB and works (it's my first promise).
        const appArray = ["5f8f25d554f1e43f3089ea5d",
        "5f8f25e854f1e43f3089ea5e",
        "5f8f25f454f1e43f3089ea5f",
        "5f8f314ab92c7f406f28b83a",
        "5f8fe50a9d44694cad91a01b",
        "5f92e8a75d848870e015dff3",
        "5f92e8b35d848870e015dff4",
        "5f92e8cb5d848870e015dff5",
        "5f8fe51d9d44694cad91a01c"];

    //the second promise takes the array above and validates it against another collection on mongoose
    function myPromise2 (response){
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            let appoints = [];
                response.forEach(e => {
                    //loop through each item of the array and look against Appointment collection
                    Appointment.findById(e, function(err, foundApp){
                        //some validation supposed to happen here and then pushed into a new array
                        appoints.push(foundApp);
                        console.log(appoints);
                    })
            }) 
            //once completed supposed to resolve and return
            resolve(appoints);
        })
    };

    myPromise2(appArray).then((response) => {console.log(response)});
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example which should work. Add a promise for each element to the array and then resolve the outer function if all promises have resolved.

```
// dummy data of an array - this is originally extracted from a mongoose DB and works (it's my first promise).
const appArray = ["5f8f25d554f1e43f3089ea5d",
"5f8f25e854f1e43f3089ea5e",
"5f8f25f454f1e43f3089ea5f",
"5f8f314ab92c7f406f28b83a",
"5f8fe50a9d44694cad91a01b",
"5f92e8a75d848870e015dff3",
"5f92e8b35d848870e015dff4",
"5f92e8cb5d848870e015dff5",
"5f8fe51d9d44694cad91a01c"];

// the second promise takes the array above and validates it against another collection on mongoose
function myPromise2 (response) {
  let appoints = [];
  response.forEach(e => {
    appoints.push(new Promise((resolve) => {
      //loop through each item of the array and look against Appointment collection
      Appointment.findById(e, function(err, foundApp) {
        //some validation supposed to happen here and then pushed into a new array
        resolve(foundApp);
      })
    }))
  })
  return Promise.all(appoints)
};

myPromise2(appArray).then((response) => {console.log(response)});
```

Comment: thank you very much for this solution. It's amazing how a simple line of code solved my problem, which I battled with for a week. More so it gave me better insight for future problems. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Points to address:

- Use the promise that mongoose provides through the `.exec()` method. This way you don't need `new Promise`
- Collect these individual promises in an array (use `.map` instead of `.forEach`), and pass this array to `Promise.all`

If you do this, the code for `myPromise2` reduces to the following:

```
function myPromise2 (response){
    return Promise.all(response.map(e => Appointment.findById(e).exec()));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

here is my suggestion:

```
 const appArray = [
              "5f8f25d554f1e43f3089ea5d",
              "5f8f25e854f1e43f3089ea5e",
              "5f8f25f454f1e43f3089ea5f",
              "5f8f314ab92c7f406f28b83a",
              "5f8fe50a9d44694cad91a01b",
              "5f92e8a75d848870e015dff3",
              "5f92e8b35d848870e015dff4",
              "5f92e8cb5d848870e015dff5",
              "5f8fe51d9d44694cad91a01c"
             ];
                
 function myPromise2 (response){
     return Promise.all(response.map(id) => {
        return Appointment.findById(id).exec();
        })
     };
                
 myPromise2(appArray)
  .then(console.log) // response array
  .catch(// handle errors)
 // you can also async/await the calling part
```

you can also use one of:

1. [Promise.allSettled](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/allSettled)
2. [Prmoise.any (es2021)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/any)
3. [Promise.race](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/race)

it's just depends on how you would like to handle the responses/failures.

Answer (score -1):

A good alternative to consider maybe Async/Await and have a look [Async_await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Async_await). This will hopefully answer all your issues

It's probably a good idea to look into how the JS event loop system works [guide here](https://flaviocopes.com/javascript-event-loop/),

Comment: This makes it a little easier to learn promises and async tasks at first by using the await keyword to wait for some async task to finish.